# If citations aren't provided, should I edit someone elses answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, citations

Over the last month or so there have been productive questions surrounding citation ([When to use citations](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/when-are-citations-needed-in-an-answer?lq=1), [how to combat unreferenced answers](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/an-effective-measure-to-counter-unreferenced-answers?cb=1)).

In [a recent answer regarding bad eyesight](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/45076/3553) there was a line that I don't think has any supporting evidence -- the author disagreess. The author provided a reference, however it didn't exactly support the statement in question. The comments lead me to believe that the answerer thinks that the statement has merit. This situation has come up a few times with me before, and I'm sure others - a partially unreferenced answer has an author that disagrees with a reader about the legitimacy of a citation. This hasn't really been covered in the aforementioned meta posts.

Assuming that one has downvoted and engaged with the answerer, what can/should be done to resolve the disputedly referenced statement. As I see it here are my options:

- High road the author and remove the line myself

  - directly conflicts with what the answerer thinks is an important line
- Flag for moderator attention (and deletion/banner)

  - overkill for answers if there is another option
- Do nothing more; future readers can evaluate the comments and merit of the answer for themselves. (*Agreeing to disagree is not ideal!*)

  - it's not entirely fair to expect readers to read through extended commentary

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the first option which you posed is most reasonable, however, only if as you said, there is at most **one** unreferenced line. For anything beyond that, I'd say that option 2 would then be the most appropriate. Option 3 should, in my opinion, not even be an option, since, in my eyes, an argument would most likely end up in an extended discussion, and that's not really what comments are there for.